# How to cut string after certain HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, truncate

I want to to cut text after `</b>` tag.

So for example,

```
<div class="quote"><b> Quote from: Bob </b>
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
```

Should be truncated to

```
<div class="quote"><b> Quote from: Bob </b>
```

How can I archive this?

Here is what I came up with:

https://jsfiddle.net/Babr/2q4940h1/8/

Comment: why not just use `$(".quote b").text()`

Comment: Your question doesn't seem *complete*. You should tell us: how is this trimmed when there's no `<b>` tag in it, also when it has more than 1 `<b>` tag in it, and when there are other tags in it but no `<b>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case you may do:

```
$(".quote").html($(".quote").children());
```

Would be truncated to:

```
<div class="quote"><b> Quote from: Bob </b></div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qhuLnzn8/)

Answer (score 1):

Filter out text nodes inside the div and remove them.

```js
$('.quote')
  // get all child nodes
  .contents()
  // filter out text nodes
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  })
  // remove them
  .remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote"><b> Quote from: Bob </b> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
```

---

or replace HTML content with the `b` tag element using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method with callback.

```js
$('.quote').html(function() {
  // return the inner b tag
  return $(this).find('b');
  // or you just want to remove the text nodes then 
  // get all elements using $(this).children()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote"><b> Quote from: Bob </b> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
var bTag = $(".quote").find("b");
var textThatMatters = bTag.text() + ' reads more...';
bTag.text(textThatMatters)
$(".quote").empty().append(bTag);
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dallows/2q4940h1/13/).

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
$('.quote').children('b').text()
```